# Jenkins scheduler using CRON

Tags: jenkins, cron

I have to maintain an old project. In this project, they've setup jenkins job which seems to be scheduled using CRON.

The CRON configuration used is `H(10-50) 12 * * *`

From https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto, I can get some basics of CRON. I can get that the second argument is hours. Which means every 12th hour.

But I not able to get what  `H(10-50)`  denotes.

From http://www.scmgalaxy.com/scm/setting-up-the-cron-jobs-in-jenkins-using-build-periodically-scheduling-the-jenins-job.html it seems  `H(0-29)/10 * * * *` can be used to schedule a job for every ten minutes in the first half of every hour.

So does `H(10-50) 12 * * *` means, to run the job for every 12th hour between 10 to 50 minutes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will run the job on any random minute between 10 - 50 at hour 12 of everyday.

- on day 1 it may run it at 12:13
- on day 2 it may run it at 12:34
- on day 3 it may run it at 12 : 49

etc.